# How to stop a sound while another sound is running?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner on Android Studio and I'm experimenting simply projects with sounds connected with a button. When I press a button the sound starts, but when I press  another button, the first sound doesn't stop. How can I resolve this problem?

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bottoneYoshi;
Button bottoneMario;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottoneYoshi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    bottoneMario = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final MediaPlayer YoshiSuono = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yoshi);
    final MediaPlayer MarioSuono = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mario);

    bottoneYoshi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            YoshiSuono.start();
        }
    });
    bottoneMario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MarioSuono.start();
        }

    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
bottoneYoshi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MarioSuono.stop();
            YoshiSuono.start();
        }
    });
    bottoneMario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            YoshiSuono.stop()
            MarioSuono.start();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem is: if there are a lot of buttons.. have I to type 'YoshiSuono.stop()' for every other sound in the project or there's a specific method to stop every sound in the project?

Comment: in that case you might like to have a look at [Acquiring and releasing audio focus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html).

Comment: but i think typing YoshiSuono.stop() shouldn't be much of a work. as you have to stop one MP in order to play anther without overlapping.